# geom regression line hidden behind binned areas of plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add a regression line with geom_smooth in a plot with binned data. The line appears but is hidden behind the binned area of the plot. I'm trying to figure out how to get the geom_smooth object to appear in front of it.

```
Nbin <- 150
bindata <- with(DEMtestf50, condense(bin(Delta_z, find_width(Delta_z, Nbin)),bin(veg_height, find_width(veg_height, Nbin))))
smoothBinData <- smooth(peel(bindata), h=c(15, 15))
plot.new()
ggplot(data= bindata, aes(veg_height, Delta_z, fill = .count))+
geom_smooth(data= bindata, aes(veg_height, Delta_z, col="Tree height vs DEM error"), method = "lm")+
geom_tile() + ggtitle("Tree Height vs DEM Error") + 
ylab("Tree Height (m)") + xlab("Delta Height (m)")
```

[image]

Comment: ggplot2 works with layers. I think calling geom_smooth AFTER geom_tile will do the trick...

Comment: Try adding transparency using alpha.

Comment: Yeah, i didn't realize the order of the layers had that effect. Swapping the order fixed it thanks.